# Sci-fi novel about a group of astronauts who discover a cylindrical world

Tags: story-identification, novel

In primary school there was a sci-fi novel that scared me into remembering it, I'm now looking to revisit it. This was about 19 years ago, and I estimate it to have been written in the 80's or very late 70's. Sadly the school is not around any more.

It's set in space.

A group of... astronauts find a (or several?) cylinder style world with a city on it.

It's like a rectangular city block with a half cylinder dome above it.

Inside they encounter some worm/snake like creature (or robot) that's black and yellow I believe, which hunts them in a very horror-esque manner.

The cover I recall as having the cylinder-style world in space, the astronauts and the snake thing.

I've been looking for this book on and off for the last 10 years.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published?

Comment: Cylindrical as in Rama-like? https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/31548627-rendezvous-with-rama

Comment: @LogicDictates thank you! I'd say about 19 years ago. And I will estimate it to be written in the 80s or very late 70s.

Comment: @Valorum I've looked at the art work in rama and it's not that. The cylindrical world in this booknis more. Imagine central park with a cylindrical roof

Comment: @LogicDictates I want to belive the world thing was referred to as a monolith. But not in the 2001 oddessy big black slab kind of monolith

Comment: Like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7N0u.png

Comment: Was there a scene in which the lights came on in the cylinder all at once?

Comment: If the interior was basically flat (not curved up on the sides) are you sure it was in a cylinder?  The [Stanford torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanford_torus) was an alternative space colony design to the [O'Neill cylinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O%27Neill_cylinder) and a view along the torus kind of looks like [flat land with an arched glass window above](https://s3files.core77.com/blog/images/321021_81_39727_y4LFKsgzG.jpg).

Comment: Did the snake like creatures make any sounds?

Comment: could it be a crab like thing instead of a snake? Seriously it sounds so like rendezvous with rama and its sequels. If not, is it Eon by Greg Bear? 20 plus years since I read that one, anyone with a better memory than mine want to comment?